# Do not require exact search in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I am trying to create a search function in PHP that does not require an exact search, ie if you search for "mar" it will return "mark" and "mary".

So far, I have the query below, but its not doing what I'm expecting.

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `first_name` LIKE ? OR `last_name` LIKE ? OR `phone` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ? or `spouse` LIKE ? OR `spousephone` LIKE ? OR `spouseemail` LIKE ? OR `child1name` LIKE ? OR `child2name` LIKE ? OR `child3name` LIKE ?");
```

Here is the full code for the function that I have created, maybe someone can advise the proper way to write it as I'm a noob with PHP & MySQL.

```
    public function visitor_search($search_query) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `first_name` LIKE ? OR `last_name` LIKE ? OR `phone` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ? or `spouse` LIKE ? OR `spousephone` LIKE ? OR `spouseemail` LIKE ? OR `child1name` LIKE ? OR `child2name` LIKE ? OR `child3name` LIKE ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(2, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(3, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(4, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(5, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(6, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(7, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(8, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(9, $search_query);
    $query->bindValue(10, $search_query);

    try {
        $query->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: you need wrap the values for each `?` in `%mar%`, or just `mar%` if you want to match start with only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to escape special chars, `\`, `%`, `_`.
Even if you use prepared statement, you have to escape these chars.
(This means you have to escape `\` **twice** without prepared statements)

Example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo LIKE ? AND bar LIKE ?');
$params = array(
    '%' . addcslashes($foo, '\\_%') . '%',
    '%' . addcslashes($bar, '\\_%') . '%',
);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

P.S.

```
public function visitor_search($search_query) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `first_name` LIKE ? OR `last_name` LIKE ? OR `phone` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ? or `spouse` LIKE ? OR `spousephone` LIKE ? OR `spouseemail` LIKE ? OR `child1name` LIKE ? OR `child2name` LIKE ? OR `child3name` LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $params = array_fill(0, substr_count($sql, '?'), '%' . addcslashes($search_query, '\\_%') . '%');
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

You should catch PDOException externally.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` does not automatically behave different from `=` as long as you do not add wildcards to the input parameters.

The following query will only find rows where `string` is *equal to* "Hello":

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE string LIKE "Hello";
```

The following query will find rows where `string` *contains* "Hello":

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE string LIKE "%Hello%";
```

As you didn't include the code where the query is actually executed, I can only assume that you missed adding those `%`s.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: you are right but in this case he is using the parameters queries.

Comment: Of course, but the issue remains the same. I just wanted to keep it simple by using plain SQL as an example.

Answer (score -1):

What happens is, you should append the % as suffix or prefix.
In prepared queries the ? will be replaced by the var content in case of text a '' will be added. To solve that you should add before send the var to query the % chars.

Please check:

```
$search = '%'.$_GET['search'].'%';    
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `first_name` LIKE ? OR `last_name` LIKE ? OR `phone` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ? or `spouse` LIKE ? OR `spousephone` LIKE ? OR `spouseemail` LIKE ? OR `child1name` LIKE ? OR `child2name` LIKE ? OR `child3name` LIKE ?");
```

result=$query->execute(array($search,$search,$search,$search,$search,$search,$search,$search,$search,$search));

Comment: Why I receive a negative?

Comment: This has a problem: `'%'.$_GET['search'].'%'`